# Creating scene layer package in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, scene-layer-package

I have a multi-patch layer in ArcGIS Pro 2.0 and I want to share the layer to ArcGIS Online. I cannot figure out how to save the multi-patch layer as a scene layer package. Under ArcGIS Pro Share tab, I can only see project, map, layer and geoprocessing package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Geoprocessing tool called Create Scene Layer Package and then you can upload that package to ArcGIS Online to create a Scene Layer. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-scene-layer-package.htm

Comment: Thanks Russ! After I created the scene layer package, who to add the web scene layer back to my scene before sharing?

Comment: So you will upload to AGOL(Through Add Item in browser or Share Package tool in Pro). Then you publish a Scene Layer from the SLPK in AGOL. Then you can add it into the Scene Viewer with Open in Scene Viewer button on the scene layer or Add Layer in Scene Viewer or you can add it back in Pro through Add Layer> My Content.